# Meaning of torsion points in a Roitman's theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, schemes, algebraic-k-theory, chow-groups

I am having some problems  to understand the meaning of the  following  theorem due  to Roitmann. I found this theorem in Voisin's book: Hodge Theory and Complex Algebraic Geometry, Volume II, page 289.

Theorem 10.14.
The Albanese map
\begin{equation*}
    alb_X:CH_0(X)_{hom}\rightarrow Alb(X)
\end{equation*}
Induces an isomorphism on torsion points.

What does it mean that the isomorphism is on torsion points? what is an  intuitive way  to think about  torsion points?

Comment: It means that the subgroups on the left and right consisting of torsion points are isomorphic.

Comment: Perhaps the confusion is that on the left we have a group on the right a group variety. The term "torsion points" refers to points in the group variety $Alb(X)$ which are torsion. On the left hand side this is just torsion elements of the group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It occurs to me that your question shouldn't be taken literally, and is simply asking about the meaning of the theorem. To appreciate it, one can  ask what $CH_0(X)$ looks like. As a first attempt, map it to something more concrete like the Albanese (which is just a complex torus over $\mathbb{C}$). It is easy to see that the map is surjective, and an isomorphism for curves. In higher dimensions, Mumford  showed that the kernel can be huge. Given this, Roitman's theorem that the Albanese map restricted to the torsion subgroups yields an isomorphism is pretty surprising. For example if $H_1(X,\mathbb{Z})=0$,  the theorem would imply that the torsion subgroup of $CH_0(X)$ is trivial.